# How is the proper number of lags for ACF or PACF displaying?

Tags: autocorrelation, lags, partial-effect

How many lags should be used for ACF or PACF displaying if we have $S$ seasonality?

For example,

for 500 observations I have 25 lags
for 200 observations I have 22 lags

It is independent from frequency of seasonality (for $S = 7, 14, 50, 60, ...$ number of lags on the picture is the same). Is it enough for model estimation based on ACF/PACF for high frequencies?

We do not need to show lags for few periods; for example, for $S=50$ at least 170 lags (it contains 3 periods)? Sorry, but available materials show different approaches.

Answer (score 4):

There's no fixed rule. It is a function of the noise in the time-series. I would show at least until no data-point crosses a confidence interval or $\frac{n}{10}$, whichever comes first.

Shown below are realizations of seasonal trend at lag of 7, with white noise $\sim\mathbb N(0,0.1)$ and $\sim\mathbb N(0,0.3)$. The confidence intervals were calculated by $\frac{\text{PPF}(0.99)}{\sqrt{n}}$ assuming the noise is distributed normally.

[image: Small Noise]
[image: Large Noise]
EDIT:
Here's another plot of lag, with more of the ACF and PACF shown:
[image: Small Noise, more plot]
Here's another plot with a higher period.
[image: Small Noise, more plot, higher period]

The code used for the figures:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statsmodels import api as sm


def main():
    prototype = np.random.random(60)
    for _ in xrange(560 / 60):
        prototype = np.concatenate((prototype, np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 60) + prototype[:60]))
    prototype = prototype[60:]
    n = prototype.shape[0]
    pa = sm.tsa.pacf(prototype, 100)
    acf = sm.tsa.acf(prototype, nlags=100)
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(prototype)
    plt.title("Time Series with a Lag of 60, White Noise of .1")
    plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(prototype.reshape(-1, 60).T)
    plt.title("Overlapping Windows")
    plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
    plt.plot(acf)
    z = stats.norm.ppf(0.99)
    c = '#660099'
    plt.axhline(y=z / np.sqrt(n), linestyle='--', color=c)
    plt.axhline(y=-z / np.sqrt(n), linestyle='--', color=c)
    plt.title("ACF")
    plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
    plt.plot(pa)
    plt.axhline(y=z / np.sqrt(n), linestyle='--', color=c)
    plt.axhline(y=-z / np.sqrt(n), linestyle='--', color=c)
    plt.title("PACF")
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you for examples. I understand using of max for axis x =50 for period=7 because of short periodicity. Could you show example with period=60 (or more) in 500-observations time series? It would be very useful. It means at least 200 lags??

Comment: 25 lags for example 2 would be enough? I have looked on Overlapping Windows plot. It can identify the number of lags?

Comment: I added two more plots and the code used to make the last one. The overlapping windows isn't used to identify the season order. That's just every season period overlaid on itself. If you care about inference, then you show a delicately made model with evidence like the PACF plot. If you care about predictive accuracy, then you just append steps that successively detrend the series. Fitting a seasonal model to the overlapping windows is relevant here. For one such model see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71208/how-to-approach-forecasting-time-series-data/71432#71432

Comment: Also: Analyzing fake time series sometimes produces weird results because of the random number generator in whatever language you're using. These are based on the Mersenne twister, which occasionally produces very odd results.

Comment: Thank you! It is a little more clear. I have to analyse hyperlinked model. Really, the overlapping windows can be very useful. But first we have to know what periods are in the series. Could you make your script on my data? I have big problem, because I cannot get white noise on residuals. I belived that period in my data is 80, but it is bad. Maybe multiseasons is needed? Could you look on my time serie: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80710/arima-with-difficult-seasonality-in-r ?

Comment: Maybe periodogram (for seasonal periods checking) should be used in this time series? And after that overlapping windows?

Comment: you can use spectral analysis to determine periodicty of time series data.

Comment: I looked at your data, it was pretty easy to predict. I did random forest regression on the once differenced data using a lag matrix of 100 lags at an immediate horizon. You just need a more flexible model. The period is definitely 80.

Comment: Really?? Have you checked ACF residuals? It has no significant values on 80, 160, 240 lags?? Residulas are white noise??

Comment: @forecast, I have used periodogram, but it does not show clear peaks.

Comment: Jacob, random forest regression will deal with data which in  some moment are not adjusted to 80 lags? Such shift. Not 111222333444555666777888, but 11122233344455566666777888? It will be good method for this case?

Comment: Jacob, and second question: random forest regression can be use for forecasting something like this: 1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,13,14,14,15,15,16,18,... - increasing values, not regular

Comment: @KateRin Any nonparametric model works. You just difference the values first. Then put that into a lag matrix with the response vector at your forecast horizon. The lag mat is circulant like. For a forecast horizon of 1, a lag order of $i$ and a time-series of length $n$, if your time-series is $x_0, .., x_i, .. x_n$, then the first observation of your lag matrix is $x_1 - x_0, .., x_i - x_{i-1}$ and your first response is $x_{i+1} - x_{i}$. The second observation is $x_2 - x_1, .., x_{i + 1} - x_{i}$ and your second response is $x_{i+2} - x_{i+1}$. and so on.

Comment: Jacob, what does <code>i</code> mean in my time series? In based on your instruction I will build vector of responses. What should I do with this vector? Could you attach any example of analysis? Or some literature? It is VAR analysis?

Comment: You do regression using neural networks, random forests, Gaussian Processes or another high variance nonparametric model. Does that make sense?